# Solution to a non-convex problem — LP with unit norm constraint

Tags: optimization, non-convex-optimization

Given a linearly independent set, $\{a_i\}_{i=1}^n$, where $a_i\in\mathbb{R}^m$ and $m\gg n$. How to find a solution to the following optimization problem?

$$\begin{array}{ll} \underset{a \in \mathbb{R}^m}{\text{minimize}} & \displaystyle\left\langle a, \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{a_i}{\left\Vert a_i\right\Vert}\right\rangle\\ \text{subject to} & \langle a, a_i\rangle>0 \quad\forall i\in\{1,2,\dots,n\}\\ & \left\Vert a\right\Vert=1\end{array}$$

Please, note that:

- $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ denotes the inner product.
- I would prefer to understand how to solve this for strict inequalities constraints, but it is ok anyway.

The problem is a good fit for LP but, unfortunately I can't find a work around the unit norm constraint. To get around the strict inequalities, I was thinking maybe I can use $\langle a,a_i\rangle\ge e^{-t}$ inequalities for some big value of $t$. I want to use `scipy.optimize.linprog` to solve this, but don't know how to incorporate the unit norm constraint.

Comment: Trying to simplify: you can assume without loss of generality that $||a_i||=1$ for all $i$.  Then your objective is $a\cdot v$ for $v\equiv\sum_i a_i$.

Comment: Thanks, yes. but still that wouldn't help with the unit norm constraint, right?

Comment: not directly, yes.....

Comment: My guess is if you had $a \cdot a_i\ge0$ for all $i$, then the optimal $a$ is going to be $a_i/||a_i||$ for some $i$ (thinking of it geometrically).  So if you must have $a \cdot a_i>0$ then pick a point just inside the feasible region from there, with norm 1.

Comment: The proof would be something like this: say $b$ is the optimal vector.  Then $b$ is in the convex space defined by the $a \cdot a_i\ge0$ constraints.  So you can write $b$ as a linear combination of the $a_i/||a_i||$'s, so you can improve the solution by picking the $a_i/||a_i||$ that has the smallest dot product with $v$.

Comment: @TickaJules Thanks. First, there is no assumption that the inner product of $a_i$'s with themselves are positive, but there is a proof that these exists a vector that its inner product is positive with each of the $a_i$'s. Second, as $m\gg n$ we are probably not able to write a vector as linear combination of $a_i$'s, right? Third, you are correct but just choosing from the feasible region is not a solution to the optimization though.

Comment: An equality constraint on norms makes the problem non-convex (and non linear). Consider the points on the boundary of a circle, they are don't form a convex set

Comment: It is correct, changed the title accordingly.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo, They are a vector in $\mathbb{R}^m$, and inner product respectively.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Thanks, but how would that help with the problem?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Sorry if I have upset you. Unfortunately, that would need a redefinition and rewrite of the question to convey the same idea and I don't think it is necessary. The incentive for anyone is to help and improve the community. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to this problem is ill-posed, the solution can be arbitrarily small and close to zero. Consider $A$ be the subspace formed by $\{a_i\}_{i=1}^{n}$. Then the solution for the problem, we call it $a^*$, can be written as $a^* = \bar{a}^* + a^{\bot}$ where $\bar{a}^* \in A$ and  $a^{\bot}$ is in the null-space of $A$, i.e. $A^{\bot}$ .

Because there is the constraint $\langle a, a_i\rangle>0$, therefore the trivial solution $a = a^{\bot}, \lVert a^{\bot}\rVert = 1$ is not valid, however we can have a solution of the form $a = \epsilon_1 \frac{a_1}{\left\Vert a_1\right\Vert} +\epsilon_2 \frac{a_2}{\left\Vert a_2\right\Vert} + \cdots  + \epsilon_n \frac{a_n}{\left\Vert a_n\right\Vert} + \sqrt{1-\epsilon_1^2-\epsilon_2^2-\cdots-\epsilon_n^2}a',a'\in A^{\bot}$, where $\forall i: \epsilon_i >0$ can be arbitrarily small.

Comment: Thanks, this was really helpful.

Comment: Sure, happy to be helpful. Also I think this happened because your objective is not a positive form, like quadratic error, or likelihood/log-likelihood of some sort, cross-entropy etc. . Most of the learning objectives are from those categories.